# node js jwt malformed react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm learning backend and wrote small APIs. It all works with postman, but when I try to make this call

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const fields = {title,tags,text,imageUrl,};
      const { data } = await axios.post("/posts", fields);
      const id = data._id;
      navigate(`/posts/${id}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
      alert("Error while creating post");
    }
  };
```

I have this error

> JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed
> at Object.module.exports [as verify]

Request controller:

```
export const create = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const doc = new PostModel({title: req.body.title, text: req.body.text, 
tags: req.body.tags, imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl, user: req.userId, viewsCount: req.body.viewsCount, });
    const post = await doc.save();
    res.json(post);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Can't resolve",
    });
  }
};
```

Function call on backend:
`app.post("/posts",checkAuth,postCreateValidation,handleValidationErrors,create);`

and axios:

```
import axios from "axios";
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:4444",
});
instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.headers.Authorization = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
  return config;
});
export default instance;
```

checkAuth middleware:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
export default (req, res, next) => {
  const token = (req.headers.authorization || "").replace(/Bearer\s?/, "");
  if (token) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "secret123");
      req.userId = decoded._id;
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(403).json({ message: "forbidden request" });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json({ message: "forbidden request" });
  }
};
```

[image: headers request from network]
I don't really understand why it doesn't work while postman calls all API successfully
Thank you all

Comment: Could you share `checkAuth` middleware code?

Comment: Could you console.log `req.headers.authorization` to see if it is present? If yes, could you manually jwt.verify('pastetokenhere')?

Comment: @Animir sorry for not responding earlier, yes it works, I can say more, this jwt automatically go in headers as wrote it but I still have this malformed, i've updated the question, added screenshot of headers request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one day let me understand that I've made wrong tags format checking for the Post creation. I've made it properly and all started work :D

```
import { body } from "express-validator";

export const postCreateValidation = [
  body("title", "Insert post title").isLength({ min: 3 }).isString(),
  body("text", "Type post text").isLength({ min: 10 }).isString(),
  body("tags", "Wrong tags type").optional().isString(), //changed isArray on isString
  body("imageUrl", "Wrong URL type").optional().isString(),
];
```

Comment: If you found the answer to your question then you should mark this answer as the accepted answer, so that this post can be marked as solved.

Comment: @Daniil Galitskii Could you explain, how is this related to JWT verification?

Comment: @liguepk I have notification "You can accept your own answer tomorrow"

Comment: @Animir that is secret for me, it just started work